# How to convert text time to datetime in js

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I have some string time like "32 mins ago" or "Today 09:51", "y-day 02:25".

How could I translate this into unix timestamp? I know it is not as precise but for database sorting it will do the job.

I found multiple libraries to make those strings but none seems to be able to revert back.

Comment: U can use library moment.js to format time, usefull thing:)
https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @VasylGutnyk momentjs says it's not a valid date `moment('32 minutes ago').unix()`

Comment: U should convert your string to format required by moment.js.